# 2011 21.5" iMac - Clone SSD without having to reinstall Windows10

Tags: hard-drive, imac, ssd

2011 iMac 12,1 - i5 2,5 - 16GB RAM, 500GB HD with Windows 10 out of the box.

Want to at least replace the old hard drive to a 500GB SSD.

I understand it is not easy to install Windows 10 on those machines. Can I just clone my HDD to the SSD  without having to reinstall Windows 10?

Comment: Did you get the original Windows media/activation codes as well?

Comment: Its the free version i believe, but have my license already bought from years ago in case

Comment: Bought it in certified apple retail store , 200$

Comment: Thanks all of you for helping edit !! Im french so English is not my 1rst language 

Comment: I’m not questioning the validity of the Win license. Main issue here is that Win10 might ask for a license renewal if the hardware changes, so having the original code might make that easier.

Comment: What is the newest version of macOS that is or was installed on the Mac? This is important because this determines if the Mac has received the latest firmware updates. The version of firmware determines how hard Windows would be to reinstall. Do you have macOS installed now as a dual boot? If so, which version? Do you plan to install macOS on the new SSD? If so, which version? Do you have any thoughts about trying Windows 11?

Comment: You should also confirm you Mac has had the firmware upgrade to allow a SATA III SSD to operate at 6 Gb/s. Have you given any thoughts to adding a second 2.5" SSD instead of replacing the 3.5" HDD?

Comment: @nohillside: The OP should goto [Manage devices used with your Microsoft account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-devices-used-with-your-microsoft-account-d4044995-81db-b24b-757e-1102d148f441), click on the link and make sure the iMac is listed. If not then, register the device (iMac). Registering should insure changes in the drive arrangement will still allow Windows to be activated.